# How to solve $e^yu_x-u_y+u=xe^y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Solve $e^yu_x-u_y+u=xe^y$

$u_x-\frac{u_y}{e^y}=x-\frac{u}{e^y}$

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{e^y}$

$e^y=-x+c$,

$\eta=e^y+x,\xi=x$

$e^y=\eta-\xi$

$u(x,y)=w(\xi,\eta)=w_{\xi}+w_{\eta}-\frac{w_\eta e^y}{e^y}=\xi-\frac{w}{\eta-\xi}$

$w_{\xi}=\xi-\frac{w}{\eta-\xi}$

how can I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This linear PDE can be solved by the method of characteristics, which reads:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{e^y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{-1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{x e^y - u}.  $$

For the first equality we have:

$$\mathrm{d}x + e^y \mathrm{d}y = 0,$$ so one of the characteristics may be defined as $\xi = x + e^y$. Use now, for example, the second and third terms taking into account the relation given by $\xi$ to come up with:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{-1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(\xi - e^y) e^y - u} \Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y} =u - (\xi -e^y) \, e^y,$$  which is a 1st-order linear ODE for $u(y)$, which can be solved in terms of an integrating factor. With the help of Mathematica, we have:

$$u = e^y\, (e^y - y \, \xi) + e^y \, \eta,$$ put now $\eta$ as an arbitrary function of $\xi(x,y)$ to get the complete solution of the PDE as follows:

$$u = e^y\, \left(e^y - y \, (x+e^y) +  \eta(x+e^y)\right).$$

Hope this helps.

I will double check on my calculations and edit if necessary.

Cheers!